# Send email notification for "Completed" Tasks to Task Creator

Tags: administration, tasks

I want to notify the task creator when an assigned task is completed. I cant see a way i can do it currently in salesforce.

I do see a workaround suggested by SteveMo
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gsHvAAI

> You can't create a straight Email Alert directly from a Task using a Workflow Rule.  However, can can create a Follow-Up Task and check the "Notify Assignee" box, which will basically have the same effect.  Also, you should have the Follow-Up Task default to Status = Completed so they don't have to close out the Notification Tasks.

But i am not sure how to go about doing this. Do we create followup task through code or is there a way to automatically create a follow up tasks via UI?

Comment: You can't create an email alert on the Task object, that's why you can't use workflow or process builder to send an email alert. you can however use process builder to send a chatter post to the creator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a task from a workflow. You can set the criteria for what you need and select create task as the action. If you have time, you can wait for the spring release. This spring release will allow admins to create an email alert workflow from a task. You can also use process builder. Here is the how to link http://automationchampion.com/tag/process-builder-to-send-email-alert-for-task/